# Using RecyclerView Adapter - Error E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am using a **custom recycler adapter** to display a `text_view.xml`into a `fragment_list.xml`. However, when I customise my `fragment_list.xml`adding a `RelativeLayout` the `text_view` is not displayed anymore. 
I am getting this error message: `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

This is `my_text_view.xml`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textStyle="normal|bold"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:text="This is my @string/cast_intro_overlay_button_text">
</TextView>
```

My `fragment_item_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color">

<Button
    android:text="Back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
    android:layout_weight="0.08"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:text="Best Scores"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp">
</TextView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.example.lucadigiammarino.biogame.ItemFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.example.lucadigiammarino.biogame.ItemFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/my_text_view"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my `MyPlayerAdapter class`

```
class MyPlayerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
ArrayList<Player> players;

/**
 * Constructor for MyPlayerAdapter class
 * @param players
 */
public MyPlayerAdapter(ArrayList<Player> players) {
    this.players = players;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder((TextView) v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyViewHolder vh = (MyViewHolder)holder;
    vh.mTextView.setText(players.get(position).name+", "+players.get(position).score);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return players.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mTextView;
    public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}


}
```

And this is my `OnCreateView()` of my `FragmentItem class`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyPlayerAdapter(Score.getInstance().getPlayers()));
    }

    return view;
}
```

I really don't know where to put my hands anymore. Appreciate help guys.

Thank you in advance

Comment: where is your activity class code?

Comment: @Divyesh I am just creating the fragment inside my activity, not doing anything. Then from my fragment the method regarding the Adapter is `OnCreateView()` and it has been attached.

Comment: i mean where you define your recyclerview and fragment where you fill some data and set to your adapter.

Comment: try to say RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(); and delete the if statement where you check if view instance of recyclerview and add the adpater in onViewCreated() lifecycle methode of a fragment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your view object is not instanceof RecyclerView, but instance of RelativeLayout. So code inside your if-statement is never executed. Replace your code with this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    Context context = view.getContext();
    if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    } else {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyPlayerAdapter(Score.getInstance().getPlayers()));
```

Here you get your recyclerView instance from the layout you inflated into view instance.

Comment: Happens to us all :)